# check value exist or not in JSON object to avoid JSON exception

Tags: java, json

I am getting a JSONObject from a webservice call.

```
JSONObject result = ...........
```

When i am accessing like `result.getString("fieldName");`

If the `fieldName` exist in that JSONObject then it is working fine.If that is not exist i am getting exception `JSONObject["fieldName"] not found.`

I can use `try catch` for this.But i have nearly 20 fields like this.Am i need to use 20 try catch blocks for this or is there any alternative for this.Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can put just ONE try catch around all your stuff.

Comment: or to check things do if(typeof(JSONObject["fieldName"]) == "undefined")) { //No field set }

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is a method [`JSONObject#has(key)`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#has-java.lang.String-) meant for exactly this purpose. This way you can avoid the exception handling for each field.

```
if(result.has("fieldName")) {
    // It exists, do your stuff
} else {
    // It doesn't exist, do nothing 
}
```

Also, you can use the [`JSONObject#isNull(str)`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull-java.lang.String-) method to check if it is `null` or not.

```
if(result.isNull("fieldName")) {
    // It doesn't exist, do nothing
} else {
    // It exists, do your stuff
}
```

You can also move the logic to a common method (for code reusability), where you can pass any `JSONObject` & the field name and the method will return if the field is present or not.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that you're using [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html), you can use [`JSONObject#optString(String key, String defaultValue)`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) instead. It will return `defaultValue`, if `key` is absent:

```
String value = obj.optString(fieldName, defaultValueIfNull);
```

Answer (score 10):

Way better solution is to use optString instead of getString.

```
String name = jsonObject.optString("fieldName");
// it will return an empty string ("") if the key you specify doesn't exist
```

Comment: what is type of jsonObject in your case Mihir? pls also mention the dependency version.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your JsonObject implementation contains method called "has". It could be checks if property exist in object.

Many JsonObject implementations contains this method.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to do so, it returns undefined or a specified defaultValue instead of rising exception

```js
/* ex: getProperty(myObj,'aze.xyz',0) // return myObj.aze.xyz safely
 * accepts array for property names: 
 *     getProperty(myObj,['aze','xyz'],{value: null}) 
 */
function getProperty(obj, props, defaultValue) {
    var res, isvoid = function(x){return typeof x === "undefined" || x === null;}
    if(!isvoid(obj)){
        if(isvoid(props)) props = [];
        if(typeof props  === "string") props = props.trim().split(".");
        if(props.constructor === Array){
            res = props.length>1 ? getProperty(obj[props.shift()],props,defaultValue) : obj[props[0]];
        }
    }
    return typeof res === "undefined" ? defaultValue: res;
}
```